# c# Selenium WebDriver. Firefox browser blocks popup windows

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Firefox 19.0.2, Selenium 2.31.2.0

In set up method I enable popup blocking via firefox profile
 firefoxProfile.SetPreference("dom.disable_open_during_load", true);
This option is required as customer wants everything worked with popup blocking enabled.

In test I need to share content to external community. When I press the button external community popup appear.
The problem is when I perform this actions by hands, everything goes fine and popup doesn't block. When I try to click this button via WebDriver Firefox blocks popup.

Click button like that:

```
//kind of mouse over emulation
    new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(_element).Release(_element).Build().Perform();
    _element.Click();
```

I think problem is in differences between native button click and click performed by WebDriver. Setting `EnableNativeEvents = true` in firefox profile is not a solution, because tests become very unstable.

Maybe someone face this problem and can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Action is composed by 3 steps.

configure the action

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
builder.MoveToElement(_element).Release().click();
```

get the action

```
Action pushButton = builder.build();
```

execution

```
pushButton.perform();
```

Tell me if you improved with that.

Edit :

`.Release()` is used for a drag and drop action.

I've found 2 specs, [here](http://pragmaticqa.co.uk/blog/2009/04/selenium-rc-and-pop-up-handling/) and [here](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-HowdoIworkwithapopupwindow?). Good read.

Comment: I made all this 3 steps in one line, there is no differences between new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(_element).Release(_element).Build().Perform();   and your 3 steps for runtime

Comment: Sure you can do it in a simple line but you forgot the click() before the build()

Comment: Thansk for your reply, but Selenium WebDriver and Selenium RC are different things. According to click inside action chain, I tried:new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(ShareButtonNative).Release(ShareButtonNative).Click().Build().Perform();   and new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(ShareButtonNative).Click().Release(ShareButtonNative).Build().Perform();                                  Browser still blocks my popup.

Comment: I'm sorry that i can't provide more specific things for c#... this is not my playfield :P